# Oracle Query - Missing Defines

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I created a very simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE TMP ("ID" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE));
```

Then tried to do this:

```
DECLARE
  whatever varchar2(20) := :bananas;
BEGIN
  MERGE INTO tmp t USING 
    (SELECT whatever AS this_id FROM DUAL) d 
  ON (t.id = d.this_id) 
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
      INSERT (id) VALUES (d.this_id);
END;
```

And then enter binds

[image]

And get this error:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
DECLARE
  whatever varchar2(20) := :bananas;
BEGIN
  MERGE INTO tmp2 t USING 
    (SELECT whatever AS this_id FROM DUAL) d 
  ON (t.id = d.this_id) 
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
       INSERT (id) VALUES (d.this_id);
END;
Error report -
Missing defines
```

I've had no luck figuring out what it wants. If I replace ':bananas' with a value like 'a' it works, but not when I use a variable and bind the value. Anyone know whats wrong with my query? Thanks.

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
"CORE   11.2.0.4.0  Production"
TNS for IBM/AIX RISC System/6000: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
```

*edit*:
I've just noticed that the error is not preventing the data from being merged correctly... The error is still concerning though

Comment: What is `:bananas`?  Is this code in a stored procedure?  The parameter needs to be defined.

Comment: I just was using any name for a variable. I want to execute this as a query with clobs, but I was having this problem with "Missing defines" always appearing and was trying to remove lots of my code until I could narrow down the issue.

Comment: Re-read your comment, it is defined in the screen shot using the "Enter Binds" window on Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: What is bananas? Define bananas.

Comment: Is that not what this is? http://i.imgur.com/Kd334Ou.png Is defining it something else?

Comment: How do you execute the script .. is it `Run`  <kbd>F9</kbd> or `Run as Script` <kbd>F5</kbd>

Comment: I've been using Ctrl-Enter (Run Statement)

Comment: You tried adding a `/` at last ?

Comment: sorry, not sure where you mean to put that. I tried a few things, all syntax errors.

Comment: `DECLARE
  whatever varchar2(20) := :bananas;
BEGIN
  MERGE INTO tmp2 t USING 
    (SELECT whatever AS this_id FROM DUAL) d 
  ON (t.id = d.this_id) 
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
       INSERT (id) VALUES (d.this_id);
END;
/`

Comment: Leaves me with an error. 
    Error report -
ORA-06550: line 9, column 6:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/" The symbol "/" was ignored.
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: Seems like buggy behavior from Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: @this-Mathieu  from where is banana is comming from ? from procedure argument ? or from table ? because in the above code its not clear.

Comment: @this-Mathieu as for the error in the comment not sure what you did but the '/' should be placed with out spaces next to it .. I mean this is wrong '  /' because there are spaces .. it should be places without spaces like this '/'

Answer (score 3):

I would probable skip the DECLARE section all together and use everywhere :bananas instead of whatever.
After BEGIN put :bananas := :bananas; and you'll get no error.
Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a slash after the statement on a line of its own. Then highlight the whole block and press F5.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message. My DB column was 32 chars(`VARCHAR2(32 CHAR)`) and declared variable for filter was 64 chars(`szId varchar2(32) := :Id;`). I copied and pasted some value as input variable. For some reason I got white space in the end. So I got 33 chars and mentioned error. I made my declaration of 32 chars and started to get more meaningful error.

I your case your DB column is `VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)` and declare is `whatever varchar2(20) := :bananas;`. I may appear that `byte` is not `char` in total size.

Answer (score 0):

I've just got similar case.

After a short research the bug was found.
Where was a code

```
DECLARE
VAR001 NUMBER := NULL;
...
SELECT *
...
AND FIELD001 = VAR001
```

I have forgoten to set VAR001

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had bind OUT parameters that I tried to access before calling CallableStatement::execute().